# RadGrid not paging

Tags: c#, data-binding, telerik, radgrid, page-index-changed

I get the paging to show when the RadGrid is shown, but when I try to click for the next page the RadGrid disappears.

Here are the following screenshots that might help with this problem

[image: The asp page]

[image: This is where the RadGrid is initially loaded]

[image: This is the pageindexchanged]

Please help with some guidance to help me resolve this issue.

Comment: you don't have to take screenshots of your code, for that propurse exists the code block in the editor, use it!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `PageIndexChanged` event, since you're not doing any funky stuff there.

As Ali Issa said, you should use the `OnNeedDataSource` event, which is gonna be called when you fetch for next page.

So follow these steps:

1. Remove the following code:

   ```
   protected void RadGrid1_PageIndexChanged(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridPageChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       this.GridView1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
       GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
       GridView1.DataBind();
   }
   ```

   in your aspx file:

   `OnPageIndexChanged="RadGrid1_PageIndexChanged"`
2. And add the following code:

   ```
   protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
   {
       GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
   }
   ```

   in your aspx file:

   `OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"`

One last thing: Don't forget your `tbl` variable must be re-assigned on every server call (unless `tbl` is a `Session` variable). So, make sure tbl is at least defined in your `Page_Load` but the best would be to replace `tbl` to some Database call.

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind the grid on `NeedDataSource` event, then on `pageindexchanged` call `Gridview1.Rebind();`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly. But in the PageIndexChanged call I have added the GridView1.Rebind() and it still does not work

Comment: when u say the RadGrid disappears you mean it is disappeared completely or it is shown with no records

Comment: Also have this problem. In my case it is fully disappearing...